# Добавить задание в cron на php

Tags: php

Нужно каждую минуту выполнять несколько заданий, например загружать фото в диалог вконтакте. У меня есть база данных с логинами:паролями и id группы в вк. Мне нужно чтобы сразу у всех аккаунтов в одно время началось выполняться задание. Получается задания выполняются так

```
Первая задача выполняется ровно через минуту

Вторая задача через 2 минуты

Третья задача через 3 минуты
```

Крон прописан так

```
*/1 * * * *
```

Дополняю:
Пользователь заходит на сайт через авторизацию ВК. Подключает группу в которой нужно меня обложку через n времени. Сохраняет результат и забывает о сайте.
Дальше сайт с базы таких пользователей, ведь их будет ровно столько сколько вошло на сайт через вк и подключили обложку, должен через n времени обновлять обложку в группе. Например каждую 1 минуту. Но не получается сделать обновление через 1 минуту сразу у всех пользователей. Кол-во подключенных к сайту групп у одного пользователя может быть так же разным. Вообщем нужно что-то типа асинхронного выполнения, чтобы все задания начали выполняться в одно и тоже время каждую 1 мин

Пример аналогичного сайта:
http://live-cover.ru

Comment: cron не подходит для этого. более простой способ - долгоживущий процесс, который сам занимается распределением задач по нужному вам расписанию.

Comment: Можно по подробнее? А более сложный?

Comment: в бесконечном цикле проверяете расписание и выполняете нужные действия, когда время пришло. более сложный это тот, что вы описали.

Comment: И какая будет нагрузка на сервер? Ведь мне нужна работа 24\7. Мне почему то кажется хостинг будет грузиться если сделать while(true)

Comment: Cron это скрипт который разбудили, он выполнил что-то и уснул. Но чтобы что-то делать массово, это нонсенс. Для таких целей лучше на Java написать маленькое консольное приложение в котором будет в цикле обрабатываться всё что вам необходимо и с заданным интервалом. Для таких целей обычно используют не хостинг, а VPS с собственным набором приложений.

Comment: разумеется нужно усыплять процесс на время ожидания наступления события. тогда нагрузка будет минимальной.

Comment: Видимо вы меня не совсем поняли, дополнил первое сообщение и добавил ссылки на такие сервисы приблизительно которые создаю сейчас я

Comment: неужели некто не знает?